# Detect all Github repos which might end and might not end with .git

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I need to split the Github repository so I could get the `owner` and `repo` part.

Currently I have a regex which is working for the repo link which ends with `.git`

```
(https:\/\/github.com)(\/)([^:\/\s]+)(\/)([^:\/\s]+)(.git)
```

For example like this `https://github.com/dummy/dummy.foo.git` but I also want the regex to be able to detect and split the ones without `.git` part to proper group, such as `https://github.com/dummy/dummy.foo`

Here is the link to test my regex: https://regexr.com/3h6g3

Comment: Do you mean [**`^(https:\/\/github\.com)(\/)([^:\/\s]+)(\/)([^:\/\s]+?)(\.git)?$`**](https://regex101.com/r/JCpwZ0/1)?

Comment: @revo Strange, it works in your site but not in my site. Any idea why? https://regexr.com/3h6p3

Comment: You didn't copy / paste regex as is and you need to enable `m` flag http://regexr.com/3h6p9

Comment: @revo Thank you very much!